# How do you write integers using binary notation in Presto?

Tags: presto

When using `grouping` (with `grouping sets`), is there any way to write integers using binary notation?

For example, I want to write

```
select
    case grouping(A, B, C, D)
        when 0x0011 then 'ONLY AB'  -- 
        when 0x0101 then 'ONLY AC'
        else 'ABCD'
    end as label,

    count(*) as statements,
from T
group by grouping sets ((A, B, C), (A, B), (A, C), (A))
```

instead of

```
select
    case grouping(A, B, C, D)
        when 3 then 'ONLY AB'
        when 5 then 'ONLY BD'
        else 'ABCD'
    end as label,

    count(*) as statements,
from T
group by grouping sets ((A, B, C), (A, B), (A, C), (B, D), (A))
```

Answer (score 3):

Presto does not support base-2 literals, but you can use `from_base`:

```
SELECT from_base('1101', 2);
```